# How to split data from standard input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin

I have some number of lines in data for input:

```
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Find out the number of lines:

```
l = len(data)
```

How can I split this data into variables?
For example I have the following input:

```
1 0
2 2
0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0
```

First come 2 numbers - n, m

Then m lines with 4 values - x1, y1, x2, y2

I tried to do this:

```
for _ in range(l):
    n, m = map(int, data.readline().split())

    some_list = []
    for _ in range(m):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, data.readline().split())
        some_list.append([x1, y1, x2, y2])
    some_function_with_given_part_of_data()
```

But it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Do you receive any error with the current code?

Comment: Why your second line doesn't have 4 numbers?

Comment: What error did you get? Please make a [mre] and include the desired output too. I see four problems/inconsistencies here: 1) The second line has 2 numbers, not 4. Is the sequence supposed to repeat? 2) `data` is a list, which doesn't have a `.readline()` method. Is it actually a file object or what? 3) `some_list` is never used. Is it supposed to be passed to `some_function_...()`? 4) The outer loop runs too many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just handle it section by section

```py
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
indexer = 0
while indexer < len(data) - 1:
    n, m = map(int, data[indexer].split(" "))
    indexer = indexer + 1
    some_list = []
    for _ in range(m):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, data[indexer].split(" "))
        some_list.append([x1, y1, x2, y2])
        indexer = indexer + 1
    print(some_list)
```

## input

```
1 0
2 2
0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0
```

## output

```
[]
[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

## note

you might want to remove empty arrays from the `some_list` array

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `input()` instead of `sys.stdin`.

The value of `m` determines how many lines you need to read. Then all you have to do is read the rest in a for loop:

```py
n, m = map(int, input().split())
lines = [[int(value) for value in input().split()] for _ in range(m)]
```

You can access the values by index instead of names. `lines` is a list of lists.

First value of the first line(your `x1`) would be `lines[0][0]` for example.

Comment: Did I post a wrong answer?

Comment: I don't know how many lines to expect from the input. With input(), I don't know when to stop the input.

Comment: @niico You said: "*Then m lines with 4 values*". After reading the value of `m` in the first line, you know how many lines will come after.

Comment: Here we are talking about exactly what to do with n and m. I don't know how many of these variables will be in the input

Comment: @niico You don't need to know! You just do a for-loop `m` times. That `m` comes from user input, from the first line. Did you try the code?

Comment: I can have 1 string n and m, or maybe 10 in 1 input. Yes, I know each specific m, but I don't know the total number of m